# Is it good to Use #region in every Method that we are implementing

Tags: c#, asp.net, coding-style

Recently my Project manager asked to write comments, summary and #regions for all the work we have done till now. Even he asked to write for  the variable declaration too. Like if we declare an amount  as double then he asked us to write like this

```
  /// <summary>
    /// RegularPay declared as double
    /// </summary>
    private double m_dRegularPay;
```

And even for Get Set too

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Get and Set FirstName
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return m_sFirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            m_sFirstName = value;
        }
    }
```

And regions while implementing some code

```
   #region EmpHourly
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Employe Hourly Amount
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="EmpAmount"></param>
    /// <param name="EmpRegularHours"></param>
    /// <param name="EmpHourlyRate"></param>
    /// <param name="EmpBonusPay"></param>
    /// <param name="EmpOtherHours"></param>
    /// <param name="EmpOverTimeHours"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool GetEmpHourlyAmount(out double EmpAmount, out double EmpRegularHours, out double EmpHourlyRate, out double EmpBonusPay, out int EmpOtherHours, out int EmpOverTimeHours)
    {
     }
```

What i want to know is is it to the better way of coding standards

Comment: Ditch the m_* variables and go with Auto-Implemented Properties - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: That first comment is _horrible_.

Comment: As an aside, a method should not have so many 'out' return values. Instead, it should be a non-void method that returns a class, structure, or possibly a Tupple<,,,,>.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Commenting class fields and properties is a good practice, but the region here seems to be pointless.  I will also add that the excessive use of out variables isn't very good C# style.  You'd be better off returning an object.

Comment: Yes, it seemed like that was some sort of employee class with hours and pay classes as members.

Answer (score 6):

Regions are horrible. They just hide the code you want to look at. To me, its like trying to read a book, but somebody put a cover over every paragraph. It makes no sense.

I also think that the school commenting request deserves pushback. It adds zero value, creates busywork, and obscures the real comments (which are the code itself).

```
/// <summary>
/// RegularPay declared as double
/// </summary>
private double m_dRegularPay;
```

This says the same thing three times. It says in a comment that RegularPay is a double, that private double RegularPay is a private double, and that m_dRegular pay is a private double.

Actually, the comment and the notation indicate that *at some point in time* m_dRegularPay was a double. The private double identifiers state that *it still is* a private double.

```
private double regularPay;
```

That only states it once.

Comment: No. They hide code you *don't* want to see. Without regions, the best you can accomplish is to collapse the outline which is even more cluttered than expanding all the properties, methods and their comments.

Comment: Yes, they hide the code I want to see.  I wouldn't have opened the file if I hadn't wanted to see it.

Comment: @Ritch Melton - 99.99999999% of the time, I do not want to see every line of code in a given file. I want to see the line for which I am investigating. When you open a book, do you want to see every line of every page all at the same time?

Comment: @Ritch: How often do you want to see all the code at once?  Usually when i'm looking at the code, i want to see a specific part.  Regions (properly named and organized) can help a lot in finding that part.

Comment: No, but if you correlate pages with classes, then yes. Regions add friction. Use them if you want, but I won't.

Comment: @Ritch Melton: +1.  Regions exist to make large classes and methods more readable.  We shouldn't have large classes or methods.  Regions really just hide bad practices.  If I see regions in a code base, I cringe.

Comment: @Thomas: No, I don't want to see every line of every page.  I do, however, want to see every line of the page I am turned to.

Comment: @Brian Genisio - If all classes, expanded would a single screen of code I might agree. However, in my experience, it is common for a single class to be longer than one screen of text. Therefore, rather than equate a class to a page in a book, it more akin to a chapter and thus I do not want to see the entire chapter all at once. If a class has 20 methods each with 2-3 overloads, when maintaining a specific method, I generally do not want to see the code of everything I'm not going to be touching.

Comment: @Thomas: I suppose it is all a matter of taste at that point, but code that is hidden from me is code that doesn't tell a full story.  Regions add friction to my development by requiring me to open them up if I want to see the code.  Sometimes, depending on the IDE settings, code in regions are not even searchable.  They reduce the readability in my code, IMO and they promote bad behavior in general.  I really wish they were not part of the spec in the first place.  Code certainly doesn't need to fit on the screen, and hiding code only makes it harder to analyze.

Comment: @Brian Genisio - I think part of the problem is the what you are trying to do and how the regions are being used. If you are try to do a code review, then certainly seeing all the code helps. However, if you are trying to adjust a specific method, then seeing everything else is clutter and makes it harder to read. If each method is wrapped in a region which wraps the comments and any overloads, then collapsed, I can see all the methods in the class at a glance. In .NET 1.1, did you really want to see the expanded initialize calls every time you looked at every class? Really?

Comment: @Brian Genisio - To my mind, the bad behavior is MS putting the comment block outside the method. That means I cannot copy the method call and get its comments. I have to find the top of the comments and then the bottom of the method. When I collapse, I get two lines for each overload (comments and the method). So, I have 5 overloads, I get 10 lines instead of 1. For every method and its overloads, I want one line that shows me the scope, return type and method name. If I want to know more about that method, I can expand to see it.

Comment: ClassView shows me the class summary. The code window shows me code. I think that regions like you describe are simply trying to make the code window look like the class view window.

Comment: @Thomas: I think there is no way we will ever agree on this.  We certainly have different philosophies about developing software.  You are talking about comments being hidden inside/outside regions.  I wouldn't have that problem because my coding philosophy believes strongly against comments in most cases.  Your argument simply confuses me because I philosophically disagree with your premise.  As for the .Net 1.1 initialize example, you are talking about auto-generated code. Different. That is what partials are for.  I develop in .net 4.0.  Arguments about how things were done in 1.1 are moot.

Comment: @Ritch Melton - There are two problems with the Class View window. First, it lists every overload instead of giving me one line. Second, it requires that I jump back and forth from the class view to the code (which presumably expanded and cluttered). I do use the Class View on occasion but I'd prefer if there was a way to format the code so I get something akin to the member list you get in help which is a list of the properties and methods (collapsed) and you can drill into it to see more.

Comment: @Brian Genisio - Clearly you have never had to build a help document where you pretty much have to use comments. Still, in general I also only use comments where they are necessary (such as a help file) but they are necessary sometimes. In addition, you are discounting working with other people's code who do use comments. Partials are another way of hiding code frankly. Designer files are another way to hide code. They both move chunks of code out of sight from the code on which you are working.

Comment: @Thomas - Do you use resharper?

Comment: @Thomas - Ok, then we disagree on regions. If we worked together, they'd be constantly disappearing out of the source tree. ;)

Comment: @Ritch Melton - And constantly reappearing ;>

Comment: @Ritch Melton - There is a way to get the equivalent of what I want without using regions: never use comments on fields, methods or properties, never use private member variables with a property (i.e. always use auto properties no matter what) and never use overloads. In that scenario, collapsing produces the equivalent of what I want. Of course, there is lots of code that uses one or more of those three and the older the .NET version the more common they are. In addition, you are really stuck if you have to produce an API doc file and don't want to use comments.

Comment: You can check out some of Brian's code here: (ActionLinq) https://bitbucket.org/briangenisio/actionlinq/wiki/Home

Comment: Here's other code that comes out of my shop: http://elevate.codeplex.com/ I haven't contributed, but it follows the style I like.

Comment: @Thomas: I don't consider API documentation to be code OR comments.  It is a different thing all together.  So, yes, I do that.  Still, nothing wrong with seeing that.  I certainly don't need to collapse them.  I disagree that Partials and Design files are a way to hide code.  They are a way to separate code.  There is a distinct difference between separation and hiding.

Comment: @Brian Genisio - Do you use the collapse feature in VS? I.e., the +/- next to sections, like methods, to collapse them to a single line? Isn't that hiding code? How is that any different than having that method and its overloads in a single region that is collapsed?

Comment: @Thomas: No, I don't use the collapse feature.  I don't want it.  I don't use it.  I don't want code hidden from me.  I never want that.  If I open a class, I want to see all the code.  Period.  My classes tend to be small.  My methods tend to be small.  Hiding code is an indication that my code needs to be refactored.  It is an anti-feature.  Hmmmm... wondering how else I can say this... :) Oh!  I don't even like it that Stack Overflow hides the comments of this particular question.  Clicking to expand adds friction.  Like I said, we are unlikely to change each others' minds.  :)  Cheers :)

Comment: @Thomas: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/the-problem-with-code-folding.html

Comment: @Brian Genisio - So you reduce your font so you can see the entire code page (or web page) on a single screen right? After all, if you have to scroll, anything off the bottom of the screen is (OMG) hidden! Heaven forbid you have page down multiple times. Clearly also, you only ever work with your own code and are always reading the entire class structure every time you make a change to a class right? That nearly every IDE vendor (if not all by this point) has a code collapsing feature is a pretty good indication that most developers want that feature.

Comment: @Thomas: Did you read the coding horror article?  I'm not alone.  I am not sure why it is so clear that the only code I ever read is my own. That is a big leap. I've been working on teams for 11 years.  I can tell you are getting riled up :)  I'll keep this going... why not?  Yes, the human mind can only look at one screen's worth of content at a time. Better yet, most humans can only concentrate on one or two lines at a time. That is how we work. That isn't an argument for hiding things. Going back to the book example, we would never consider hiding lines because we only see a few at a time.

Comment: @Thomas: Also, arguing that the existence of features in an IDE qualifies them as good ideas is like arguing that `goto` in C# is a good idea.  Or like arguing that slavery is a good idea because people used to do it. (working towards Godwin's law here, if you can't tell)  People THOUGHT they wanted code folding, but the feature actually created more problems that it solved.  Code folding is a tool to quiet the masses.  Hitler used tools to quiet the masses, and you see what happened there!  (Boom, I just did that.)

Comment: @Brian Genisio  - I did read the article. Did you read the comments? I too am not alone. By definition, scrolling is a way of hiding information. Without it, we would have to see the entire contents all at once. Using the book analogy, we would never consider showing the entire chapter on a single page. There is a reason why a large format for books is not conducive for regular reading. I'm not really riled up but I have had this same argument with other developers. The best analogy in the comments was that code folding is like a knife: it can be used for good or ill.

Comment: @Brian Genisio - (C# has a goto statemnt?! Who knew?). Granted, it is a bit of an ad populum but clearly many, many developers wanted code collapsing as the vendors of products with it used it as a selling point against MS for years. Frankly, code folding is invaluable at seeing the top level structure. Hell, the class view alone is a form of code folding as it provides a top level view of the class structure (it is close to but not exactly the view I want). RE: Godwin. Heh, you forgot to mention that a kitten is killed whenever you fold code :)

Comment: @Thomas: Honestly, I can't disagree with the "knife" example.  I use a knife for cooking, not for cutting paragraphs out of my book. :)

Comment: @Brian Genisio - Rabbit season! Duck season! Rabbit season! Duck season! Fire!...

Comment: @Thomas: Code folding is actually REALLY good for presenting code, because they allow you to focus and talk about the code you are speaking about.  Code folding is really bad for developing/refactoring/reading classes.

Comment: RE: Kittens.  Nah, I reserve killing kittens for code comments (really old post of mine): http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2008/07/19/comments/

Comment: @Thomas: I see the class view as a different tool.  It is not code hiding, it is for high-level structure, like you said.  A table of contents, if you will.  When I am in an editor, I want to see the code.

Comment: @Brian Genisio - When I'm an editor I *sometimes* want to see all the code. Often, I want to focus on one area of the code and not others. It depends on the circumstance. There are many times when I want to filter out the stuff that isn't directly relevant to the code on which I'm focusing.

Comment: @Brian Genisio - So, suppose you have a class with 5-10 methods or so that you have been maintaining for the past couple of years and you need to add a method. Each time you go into that class, you read through the entire class including its using statements and all the code in all the methods? Sounds wasteful to me.

Comment: @Thomas: Of course I don't read the entire thing in that case.  BUT, I certainly don't want to hide anything.  Unless I am developing a purely functional library (very rare), my class maintains state which means methods don't live in isolation.  Modifications to code produce side effects.  The last thing I want to do is hide the code from visibility.  Doing so only requires me to move my mouse and click on "expand".  Why would I want to add that friction to my workflow?  Instead, I use my hot-keys to jump around within the code.  I grow weary of this thread.  We won't convince each other.

Comment: @Brian Genisio - On the point that we won't agree, we agree. Like I said, Duck Season!

Answer (score 6):

This commenting convention seems overzealous...but inconsistently so.

It is silly busy work to annotate the line `double RegularPay` with the comment, "RegularPay declared as a double". That is obvious, and pointing it out is superfluous and a waste of time.

In your region, the summary for GetEmpHourlyAmount could be important, but it is not treated as such. The name of the method is just as useful as the comment.

Generally, if you comment, the comment should tell you something that the names do not obviously tell you. The comment should display more helpful information.

Comment: Right, it depends on the quality of the comment.  The example comments are redundant, but I've often wished for more information about the purpose and intended usage of fields that their names didn't give me.

Answer (score 3):

IMO Regions are a code smell. They affect `readability` as well as `maintainability`. You need regions when have a large code file and need to compartmentalize code. However, you should really be writing small classes, each doing it's own task.

While editing code files with regions, it is a pain to decide in which region you want to put your new methods in etc. I have often seen that the many regions contain the code that should belong to another region.

Commenting properties is fine but you should also write the purpose\use of the property to make things clearer. Ideally purpose should be evident from the name itself.

I think it is pointless to write comments like the 'field is declared as double'. The IDE intellisence already does the job making the comment redundant.

Also, consider using [auto properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) to remove boilerplate code.

Comment: If you have a large code file, you have other problems.  Break up the class or go for partial classes instead.

Comment: Not to mention when that field stops being a double, but the comment isn't updated.  Comments get stale, code doesn't.

Comment: That regions affect readability is debatable. How do they affect maintainability exactly?

Comment: @Thomas - Suppose you have a large file with regions, and lets say you have two regions for two interface implementations, then you want to add a private method which is used by code in both regions, where do you write it? Then may be you will create a third region with name 'private methods'. After that you just use the IDE to create a new private method or extract a method, it is added below your public method. Then you have to move it to the private method's region. and so on .. is it not a pain?

Comment: @Unmesh Kondolikar - The methodology you use in your regions is obviously critical. Suppose you have a large file where each method is wrap in a region (rather than large generic sections) where the region name is the method scope and name. Why you ask? So that when you collapse the document, the comments of the method get collapsed with the region and not as a separate line (and get greyed out).

Comment: @Unmesh Kondolikar - Btw, I whole heartedly agree with not creating arbitrary regions like Public methods, Private Methods etc. for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like massive overkill to me.

Documenting self describing methods/variables for the sake of documenting them is such a waste of money.  They get stale, out of date and make the code harder to read.

Moreover - using regions is a sign of code smell.  If you have such a large class that you have to break it up into regions you need to rethink the design.

Documentation and Regions won't fix bad code, and make it harder to maintain.  Good code is self describing, and shouldn't need blanket rules like "comment everything".

Comment where appropriate, and use regions as a warning sign that you need to fix your file's structure.

Answer (score 2):

I think better way for using regions is logical grouping of functions and function parts if function is large. For function description summary is enough, i think.

Answer (score 2):

Comments that state the painfully obvious are worse than no comments at all.  Besides adding noise to the code, they also tend to get out of sync with the code they describe, and end up flat-out lying about what the code does.

Instead of "Get and Set FirstName", if there really must be a comment there, i might change the comment to something like "Gets or sets the employee's first name".

Instead of "RegularPay calculated as double", i'd have...well....a better name for the variable.  VS makes it so easy to rename a variable, and so easy to just mouse over a variable and see what it is, that the best documentation would be the code itself in a more descriptive form.

As for `#region`s, iff the region will contain significantly more than one method, then a *clearly named* region might help.  For single methods, though, it's not worth the effort -- VS can already collapse methods whenever you please, so a `#region` adds noise and gains you nothing.

Answer (score 2):

These comments may be used to automatically generate documentation for the code. Check with your project manager whether this is the case.

I agree with the others that commenting what is obvious is absolutely a waste of time. Regular pay being a double is one such comment. An example, or other info not immediately apparent would be more useful. For example, "regular pay per week" or "regular pay per annum" or "regular pay in cents". These comments would be necessary because nobody in a right mind would name a variable RegularPayPerWeekInCentsExcludingOvertimeRatesAndTaxDeductions.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting variable as you have done would have no meaning as it implicitly shows 
the validity.

```
   private double m_dRegularPay;
```

says it all

Now for regions it would be best where in you have a huge code base and you can logically make placeholders say like **handlers**, **constructors**, **computation** etc ...
For a new entrant its like index of a book (could be very helpful at times)

Answer (score 0):

If you have few thousand lines of code in a class/file region could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. A Region should probably never be used inside a function or contain just one function - A simple comment or  block will suffice. If your function seems too big maybe you should consider refactoring. A region could make sense around an interface implementation *if* your class implements more than one interface.
2. A Class should probably never contain just one region - Otherwise the region is simply the class (maybe you already have a comment or  block on the class) so thats just duplicating information.
3. Place a region around your private variable declarations - this is down to your programming style, I place all my private declarations at the top of the class and 99% of the time when i open a file I am modifying a function or property so there is relly no need to see them unless I am creating something new so, for me, it makes sense to place these in a region.

Theres probably a few more maybe this list will grow over time. I am not saying use them in this way, but more if your going to use them think twice and use them wisely.